# Unsure of which API or library to get existing hiking trail coordinates/data

Tags: google-maps

I'm prototyping a google maps application and I would like to obtain the series of lat/long coordinates that make up an existing hiking trail that google maps already has drawn on a given map. See the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPfQd.png), but how would I obtain the data (ie. lat/long cordinates) on the Wonderland Trail in the screen shot. Is that a polyline, a road or something else? I tried the Roads API (both snapToRoad and nearestRoads) with a series of coordinates around the Wonderland Trail and was receiving empty responses from the API. I've searched up and down the reference docs and on this site and can't seem to pinpoint the API or library I need to use or even what type of "map element" a trail is considered to be. One item of note, and is the reason I was drawn towards the Roads API is when I toggle my map style visibility settings for arterial road labels:

```
{ featureType: 'roads.arterial', elementType: 'labels', stylers: [{ visibility: 'off'}}
```

The label on the "wonderland trail" in the screen shot disappears. Comes back when I toggle back to on. This would lead me to believe that Google Maps construct for this map element is a road. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the Directions API and request WALKING directions from one point to another on the trail and you'll be able to extract a Polyline.

Answer (score 0):

I’m unsure why @MrUpsidown didn’t post his answer as an answer but, what he said does in fact work. If you need data about an existing route (whether that is a road, trail or some existing navigation construct) the Directions Service (DirectionsService in JavaScript) does appear to be the place to go.